# which schema should i use for joomla ldap config?

Tags: joomla, ldap

i have added entry:

## !DATE 2014-01-19T11:48:56.062

dn: cn=Derek Carter2,ou=mis,ou=unit,ou=company,dc=labs,dc=com

changetype: add

telephoneNumber: 02-29587572

mail: c291677874@labs.com

objectClass: person

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

givenName: Derek Carter

sn: Carter

title: engineer

cn: Derek Carter2

**but joomla ldap config need uid field。
what else should i to enable joomla login with ldap?
change schema or add entry attrbuite?**

Answer (score 1):

uid is supposed to be globally unique.  Often it is a short name you might consider a login name value.  It is unlikely that the user wants to login as Derek Carter2 they probably want to login as dcarter or carterd or somesuch.  Do you maintain such a value?  Conversely, folk often use the email address as the login id, since it must be globally unique.  Or at worst, the stuff before the @ sign in the email address, if it is your email domain.  I.e. All users in your email domain, should have unique bits before the @ sign.

In that case, use that data in the uid attribute.  Or else change the LDAP mapping that takes the passed in login name, and looks at mail instead of uid.